# How to read .sql file from Google Drive in Google Colab?

Tags: postgresql, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory, chmod

I'm trying to play with Postgresql in Google Colab. I faced 'Permission denied' problem when I tried to import db dump that I created locally and uploaded to G Drive.
So far I mounted GDrive, installed postgresql server, created and connected to an empty db.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

#This code will take ~20 sec to execute
# Install postgresql server
!sudo apt-get -y -qq update
!sudo apt-get -y -qq install postgresql
!sudo service postgresql start

# Setup a password `admin` for username `postgres`
!sudo -u postgres psql -U postgres -c "ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'admin';"

# Setup a database with name `int_debt` to be used
!sudo -u postgres psql -U postgres -c 'DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS int_debt;'
!sudo -u postgres psql -U postgres -c 'CREATE DATABASE int_debt;'

#Connect to int_debt database
!sudo -u postgres psql -U postgres -c '\c int_debt'

#Give Colab a permission to read files from Google Drives folder 'data_for_colab'
!chmod -R 777 /content/drive/MyDrive/data_for_colab/intdebt.sql

!sudo -u postgres psql -U postgres -c '\i /content/drive/MyDrive/data_for_colab/intdebt.sql'
```

I tried to use `!chmod -R 777` to give Colab a permision to access intdebt.sql, yet last command returns `/content/drive/MyDrive/data_for_colab/intdebt.sql: Permission denied`

I also checked `!ls drive/MyDrive/data_for_colab/` and Google Colab see `intdebt.sql`